# Sqrt and decimals

Tags: math, decimal, square-root, sqrt

Is there any standard number of decimals needed to be able to reconstitute a number from it's sqrt decomposition with an *error < 1* ?

I mean this : **sqrt(200000) = 447.21359** ...
If I try to do rebuild my number with only **two decimals** I have
 **(447.21)^2 = 199996.7841** 
but if I use the first **three decimals** I get
 **(447.213)^2 = 199999.467369** which is an error less then 1 from the original number.

Is there any formula for the number of decimals I need to save ?

Comment: if you round the value to 3 digits after radix point then it'll be 447.214, not 447.213. 447.214^2 = 200000.361796

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really about math, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error will be 1 when the re-squared square root is equal to or greater than the original value +/- 1, so just find the difference between the square root of x+1 (the error is higher on the + side) and the square root of x:

```
maximum error = sqrt(x+1) - sqrt(x)
```

e.g:

```
sqrt(200001) - sqrt(200000) = 0.001118033
```

So you need 3 digits

The full formula is:

decimal digits required = ceil(-log<sub>10</sub>(sqrt(x+1)-sqrt(x)))

Comment: Nice answer and thank you for the formula, I find it correct but you need to add 1 to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Let `y` be a number, `x=sqrt(y)` its square root, and say we have an approximation `z` to the square root with error `eps = z - x`.

Then

```
abs(y - z^2) = abs(y - (x + eps)^2)
= abs(y - x^2 - 2 eps x  - eps^2) = abs(2 eps x + eps^2)
= O(eps x)
```

for small `eps`. In other words, if you want the error of the square to be less than 1, then the error of the square root should be approximately less than `1 / sqrt(y)`.

So for your example, the error should be less than

```
1 / sqrt(200000) = 0.002236....
```

or half that if you want to be more precise and take the factor 2 into account. So, as you found out, this formula gives you that you need to be precise to the 3rd digit behind the comma in your case.

Comment: (sqrt(200000)+0.0021)^2 = 200001.878301511, which is an error of more than 1

Comment: @samgak: You ignored the factor 2 in the big-Oh analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate
`a = Sqrt(200000-1)=447.2124774645716` and use such piece of Sqrt(200000) that is larger than `a`.

Here `447.21 < a`  but `447.213 > a`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer of samgak and illuminating the answer of cfh in another way:

```
 sqrt(x+1) - sqrt(x) = 1 / (sqrt(x+1) + sqrt(x) ) < 1 /  (2*sqrt(x))
```

by the third binomial formula. To separate `sqrt(x+1)` and `sqrt(x)` and `sqrt(x-1)` at roughly the midpoints of the segments between them, the modification of the exact result `sqrt(x)` should be smaller than `1 /  (4*sqrt(x))`